# How to use context inside listener?

Tags: java, android, listener, android-context

I have code like this:

```
else if (v == mSettings)
{
    if (disappearView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // start alpha, end alpha
        fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(1000); // time for animation in milliseconds
        fadeOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true); // make the transformation persist
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
        disappearView.startAnimation(out);
        disappearView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                disappearView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
                bannerView.startAnimation(in);
                bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        });
    }
    else {
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        disappearView.startAnimation(in);
        disappearView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bannerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        bannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

It all works apart from this section in the animationListener:

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
```

It wants a valid context but it is receiving an animationListener, what context do I give it, context really confuses me here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivityName.this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
```

It wants an instance of any class that extends [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Since it is inside an anonymous inner class, when you use `this` you are referring to the inner class instance, and not to your Activity. My snippet refers to the Activity class that wraps the anonymous inner class. Since [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) extends Context, this is a valid argument.

Comment: I am trying to set up onSwiped() in a RecyclerItemTouchHelper class.  It has a public interface back to the MainActivity for the onSwiped().  Is there an advantage to using a listener object and this.listener = listener versus using Context context on the onSwiped()?

Answer (score 4):

Inside the listener, `this` is referring to the `Listener`. Try using `ActivityName.this`

Comment: I am trying to set up onSwiped() in a RecyclerItemTouchHelper class. It has a public interface to notify the calling MainActivity for the onSwiped(). Is there an advantage to using a listener object and this.listener = listener versus using Context context in the constructor, for onSwiped()?